# How to get an element using inner text (Watir, Nokogir, Hpricot)

Tags: watir, hpricot

I have been expeirmenting with Watir, Nokogir and Hpricot. All of these use top->down approach which is my problem. i.e. they use element type to search element. I want to find out the element using the text without knowing element type.
e.g.

```
<element1> 
    <element2> Text2 </element2>
    <element3> Text3 </element3>
     text4
</element1>
```

I want is to get element2 and element1 etc by searching for Text2 and Text3.

Please note that I do not know if elements are divs or tr/tds or links etc. I just know the text. Algorithem should be something like :
iterated through all the elements, match inner text, if match get me the element and the parent element.

Let me kow if this is possible in any way?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but you can use the text() functionality, outlined in the [wiki](http://wiki.github.com/hpricot/hpricot/hpricot-challenge) (See *Searching Inner HTML*).

```
doc.search("*[text()='Text3']")
```

will return

```
#<Hpricot::Elements[{elem <element3> " Text3 " </element3>}, " Text3 "]>
```

You could then iterate through these and check they are actual elements:

```
doc.search("*[text()='Text3']")[0].elem?
```

Would return `true`. Whereas `[1]` would return `false`. However, where this falls down is if you were trying to find `text4` as this returns:

```
#<Hpricot::Elements["\n     text4\n"]>
```

i.e. not the actual element. So perhaps in these instances (how you determine these instances I don't know) you could check whether it's an element, and if false get the parent

```
doc.search("*[text()='text4']")[0].parent
```

Sorry I don't have a complete answer, but thought the "text()" thing would be worth mentioning for now.

Answer (score 1):

Watir has [XPath](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/XPath) support. I am not really familiar with XPath but I am pretty sure it would do what you need. Something like:

```
browser.element_by_xpath("some_xpath_magic").click
```

I would also suggest posting your question at [watir-general](http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/).